# Synchronize two document sets

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, document-set

Is it possible to synchronize two document sets?
This has to be done because we need an admin and a public view for the document set. The difference between these 2 views is that we want to have one view only showing certain elements and the admin view shall show all elements and the users could theoretically just swap between the different views which isn't sufficient.
We have to do it with two separate document sets due to guidelines that we want to use sharepoint out of the box as much as possible.
I tried solving it with the nintex workflow action "Copy to sharepoint" with the overwrite option enabled but it does some strange internal looping because it creates new elements when updating the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy single document between two docuemnt sets, use "Send To", type the address of another document set.

[image]

If you want to bulk copy documents from document set 1 to document set 2, please use "Open with explorer":

[image]